# Verifying database schema in a database-first application?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a project that quite often fails due to enormous amounts of models and the wrong approach that was taken (database-first) in such app.

While I can't remake the entire application using code-first approach, is there any way to verify database to find all missing relations, columns and errors?

I've googled a plenty about this aspect, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089448/how-to-check-if-database-schema-matches-entity-framework-schema) helpful?

Comment: @vasily.sib Just checked - it's for codefirst only. The following error pops:
'System.NotSupportedException: 'Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.'