# Creating/Updating database schema from a console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a **console application** that interacts with a backend database using EF. Core. I have the DBContext that looks as follows.

```
class HRDepartmentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=somepath\\employees.db");
}
```

It's consumed in a class that looks as follows.

```
class EmployeeManager
{
    public  CreateEmployee(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        using (var db = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // logic for employee creation
        }
    }

    // other methods for delete/update the employees
    public UpdateEmployee(...) {...}
    public DeleteEmployee(...) {...}
}
```

My questions.

a) What is the best way of calling **EnsureCreated** method as I don't want to call it in the individual Create/Update/Delete Employee methods.

b) What is the best way of handling schema changes scenarios in future versions of the application? Reading the documentation, it does not look like **EsureCreated** will be able to handle the scenario. Obviously upgrade schema need to be performed without any existing data loss.

**UPDATE:**
I want to avoid using any EF command lines for migration in case of schema changes. I prefer the code to handle it.

Comment: I think this will solve your problem, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089448/how-to-check-if-database-schema-matches-entity-framework-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089448/how-to-check-if-database-schema-matches-entity-framework-schema)

Comment: don't see how it's related to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally in netcore 3 I would use the generic `IHost` in your console application. Then configure the database services using dependency injection. And an `IHostedService` to create or migrate the database during startup.

```cs
    public class Program {
        public static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite();
            serviceCollection.AddHostedService<DatabaseStartup>();

            serviceCollection.AddDbContextPool<HRDepartmentContext>(o =>
            {
                o.UseSqlite("Data Source=somepath\\employees.db");
            });
            // configure other services here
        }

        public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build())
            {
                await host.StartAsync();
                var lifetime = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();

                // insert other console app code here

                lifetime.StopApplication();
                await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
    }

    public class DatabaseStartup : IHostedService {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        public DatabaseStartup(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<HRDepartmentContext>();
                await db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                // or 
                await db.Database.MigrateAsync();
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Since your console application then has a `CreateHostBuilder`, the entity framework command line tools can discover any custom configuration when creating migrations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing I forgot to mention in my question is that I want to avoid using any EF command line for migration. I prefer the code to handle it. Does that impact the solution you proposed here?

Comment: Automatic migration isn't supported by EF Core, and there is no plan to (see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6214). However, it is possible to build an un-supported process, which I just happen to have already done, https://gist.github.com/lakeman/1509f790ead00a884961865b5c79b630. Use at your own risk.

Comment: I cannot resolve the Host from the CreateHostBuilder from the code you provided. This caused a compilation error The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context. Any idea how to resolve it? I am using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Add a nuget reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`

Answer (score 0):

Also to create and `employee` you can use the `class constructor`, or the `object initializer`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this helps to answer the question I asked. Do you mind elaborating a little?